# Implement component supporting implicit and explicit width

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I'd like to have a row of two one-line text items. The first one should be always fully visible. The second one should add to main item's `implicitWidth` by the value of own `width` if the root item has not its `width` property set explicitly. In other case, the second text item should be elided so that it fits into remaining space.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do. The variant 1 is the first thing that came to my mind, but it does not work. The second variant shows how I expect it to be. Alas, I don't like since it requires to sum up all the child items of the `Row`. Fortunately, I have only two of them. What if I want to add more?

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    // variant 1
//    implicitWidth: row.implicitWidth
    // variant 2
    implicitWidth: Math.ceil(name.implicitWidth + value.implicitWidth)
    implicitHeight: row.implicitHeight

    Row {
        id: row
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        Text {
            id: name
            text: "Label"
        }
        Text {
            id: value
            width: parent.width - x
            text: "Value"
            elide: Text.ElideRight
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mitch I am asking because I haven't seen any exhaustive examples using `implicitWidth/Height`. I am trying at the moment.

Comment: I understand, but can you share what you have tried so far? At the moment this question is quite clear, but it doesn't show much "research effort".

Comment: Thanks. You say that you don't like the second approach because it doesn't scale well if you were to add more items, but what would you expect the behaviour to be if you added more items? I would go with the second approach. I tried a solution that involved checking the implicit width of the root item against its width, but it resulted in a polish loop.

Comment: This could become quite tricky (as pointed out by @Mitch attempts to solve it). Since "The first one should be always fully visible" should the `fontSizeMode` and the `minimumPixelSize` be set on the first text, should't they? By the way, I don't know if it can turn out useful but, when `width` is not set in a  `Text` item, `paintedWidth == width`.

Comment: @Mitch I expect the same behavior in general. Except for limitation that there can be only one stretching item like the second text. Others should be fixed.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo read "always visible" in the sence of horizontal space provided for the item. In other words, it should not shrink less than its `implicitWidth` unless the root item has width less than that. Do you mean under `paintedWidth == width` that `implicitWidth` is used to define effective `width`. If so, this is the default behavior for any `Item` (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: @DmitryVolosnykh I was just pointing out that there was another property (which probably does not adds anything). Probably a stupid sidenote. Regarding your explation of the question text, now it is a lot clearer. Thank you. :)